# efficiency and usage of dynamic vertex buffers in d3d

Tags: c++, directx

i submitted a question that was actually a bunch of questions in one, so i'm splitting them into their own separate questions, as requested.

i've read about and used dynamic vertex buffers, and manipulated them at runtime, etc. I've been told however, to keep dynamic vertex buffers to an absolute minimum, as they tend to bog down performance much more than static buffers. I've also read that rather than locking and unlocking constantly to write just a couple polygons, using dynamic buffers allows you to lump a great sum of vertices into one buffer and send them off in one go, which apparently improves performance. I'm probably going to like to be able to manipulate most of the objects in the scene constantly, ( not just by rotation or scale but by individual vertex position, etc), so is there some way to have a dynamic buffer that you only have to update or change when you have to, but otherwise does not have to be rewritten every frame?

Comment: What do you want to do with you vertices? Update them base on some stream data? Maybe you can try staging buffers.

Comment: occasionally change there position through out the lifetime of the application and add vertices as the camera approaches the side of the map. (i havn't even remotely attempted it, but this is to get a background on what procedural terrain might entail).

Comment: You can give it a test by modifying any sample in the SDK, and see if you have to upload the buffer every frame (I guess not). I found you are playing with D3D9, and I'm not familiar with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic buffer does not require a rewrite everyframe, it is just more accessible to CPU than GPU for ease of updates.  For less frequent updates, you can use static which is more accessible to the GPU for faster rendering, then use UpdateSubResource to edit just a range of vertices as needed.

Comment: well, from what i've read, i figured that a dynamic buffer had to be scrapped and rewritten every frame, whether the data written was the same or not. If they are just like a static buffer, except that they can have vertices added or subtracted occasionally, why use anything but a dynamic buffer?

Comment: Honestly - have been studying the same thing, so can not say I know for sure... but my best answer I can give is:
If vertexes will be constant - use static as the hardware will not have to worry about frequent memory updates and will render fast
Else - use dynamic and the memory updates will be faster, but the rendering will not be as fast..
Again, I hope someone gives a concrete answer, been wondering the same thing and going with my assumptions above.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205132(v=vs.85).aspx - seems to hint that dynamic is stored for fast CPU access (easy updates) and static is stored for faster GPU access (but not easily accessible to CPU for updates).

Comment: same :P . I really want to use dynamic buffers, but i'm not sure how to do it efficiently, or reasonably when the buffers will really only be updated ocasionally. If i wanted to update the buffer constantly, there'd obviously be no other way, but here i feel i would just be running the card ragged for no reason :\   
edit: this was for the comment above the last one

Comment: so i wonder if there's maybe someway to store a dynamic buffer for faster gpu access, for only occasionaly increases or decreases in polygons? would be slower to update, but would be able to increase or decrease in size.

Comment: okay, after reading that, i'm curious what it means close to the bottom about staging buffers, "cpu access of gpu". what i'm getting about staging buffers is that you can manipulate them as you please with the cpu, and can be updated by the gpu. that may be what i'm looking for but i'm not sure. i'm going to look for an example. but thank you at least for putting me on the right track, good sir with the google powers :P